# 'UnityEngine.RuntimePlatform.OSXDashboardPlayer' is obsolete

Tags: c#, android, ios, unity-game-engine, obsolete

I'm a new user trying Unity, and forgive me if this is a dumb question that can easily be solved with a single button, but I have been pulling my hair out trying to figure out why I keep getting these errors. Here is a screenshot:

> UnityEngine.RuntimePlatform.OSXDashboardPlayer is obsolete

[image]

Comment: Hi Oussama, Welcome to StackOverflow. Please consider to include your error as quoted text or attach it as screenshot. Links are not reliable and they are subject to change which makes the post unusable for the community. Please also read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I am voting to close this question because this type of question requires the error text to make any sense and screenshots are an inadequate method of including the error text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the errors message said, the RuntimePlatform.WindowsWebPlayer is **Obsolete**, same as OSXWebPlayer and OSXDashBoardPlayer.

If the issue is caused by some third-party SDK(Plugin), you could try to update it to the latest version. Or not to use it if possible.